# The MSYS2 MinGW doesn't include mingw-get package manager

Tags: mingw, msys2

I have installed the MSYS2 from [their website](https://www.msys2.org/), however, I'm not able to find the `mingw-get` package manager. I tried searching the MSYS2 packages by

```
pacman -Ss mingw-get
```

and looking into the installation folder `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` but it simply not there. My questions are:

- Does the MinGW shipped with MSYS2 include the `mingw-get` package manager?
- If not, how I can install it?

Answer (score 3):

MSYS2 doesn't include `mingw-get`, it uses `pacman` instead.

From their website:

> It features a package management system, **Pacman**, to provide easy installation of packages. It brings many powerful features such as dependency resolution and simple complete system upgrades, as well as straight-forward package building.

Pacman is much more powerful than `mingw-get` was. You should be able to install additional packages using Pacman instead of `mingw-get`.

MSYS2 was built around Pacman. So even if you *could* install `mingw-get` (like, manually downloading it and unpacking it, or rebuilding it from source), it's unlikely that it would do anything useful in an MSYS2 installation.

Adoption of Pacman also determine how the packages get built (through PKGBUILD files with the build rules), that's why MSYS2 is a *rewrite* of MSYS, where each package build has been remade from scratch. Pacman is so much at the core of MSYS2 that it's hard to detach them from each other.

(Perhaps a similar comparison can be drawn to Linux distributions. Can you install `rpm` on Debian, or `dpkg` on Fedora? Yes you can, but you most likely won't be able to use them to manage the packages installed on your distro, since the distro is built around the other package manager, which is at the core of that distro, in a way that's really hard to dissociate from it.)

Comment: I'm actually aware of `pacman` and how powerful it is. But I want to know how I can install `mingw-get` if I want to.

Comment: @Foad mingw-get is an MSYS1 thing, so even if you *can* install it under MSYS2 (like, manually downloading it and unpacking it), it's unlikely that it will do anything useful in your MSYS2 installation, which was built to be managed using Pacman instead.

Comment: Aha, so `mingw-get` is not a MinGW package manager but MSYS one?

Comment: The first MSYS was basically a part of MinGW, as you can see from the website: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS. Yes, I think it's fair to say that `mingw-get` is an MSYS1 thing and not really an inherent part of MinGW.

Comment: Or, perhaps: `mingw-get` is/was a part of MinGW that's been made obsolete in MSYS2 by the adoption of Pacman to better fulfill that role.

Comment: mingw-w64 and msys2 are forked from the earlier mingw and msys projects  (although MSYS2 may be better described as a new project than a fork)

Comment: @M.M So the MinGW shiped with the MSYS2 is not synced with the upsteram?

Comment: @Foad msys2 includes mingw-w64 (not mingw.org). Not sure what you mean by "synced with the upsteram"

Comment: @Foad You might find this page interesting: https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/History

Comment: @M.M What is the difference between MinGW-MSYS and mingw-w64-MSYS2?

Comment: @Foad See http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php: *"Mingw-w64 is an advancement of the original mingw.org project, created to support the GCC compiler on Windows systems. It has forked it in 2007 in order to provide support for 64 bits and new APIs. It has since then gained widespread use and distribution."* As for the difference between MSYS and MSYS2, I think we've got that covered, no?

Comment: I had no idea that Mingw-w64 and mingw.org are two different projects. IT is much more complicated than what I had anticipated before. So I'm going to read more. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @Foad My 2¢: Don't worry too much about these details. If it does what you want, good! If you need something different, look for an alternative. Looks like you have a high level choice between Mingw/MSYS (whatever version, but go with newest project of course) and Cygwin. So ask yourself: Do I want to build POSIX applications and run them on Windows? If yes, you want the latter, if no, the former is enough. Project histories and forks can be interesting, but that knowledge has probably limited practical usefulness to you while adopting the project... Anyways, I hope you're happy with answers!